# Windows File explorer not recognizing .json

Tags: windows-explorer, notepad++, json

Using <kbd>Notepad++</kbd> to edit some stuff for a label format that needs to be uploaded as a `.json` to the online software being used to print the label. When I save the <kbd>Notepad++</kbd> file as a `.json` and then go to file explorer to get it, it's no longer a `.json`, its a windows "File". When I try to upload it, the website gives an error that the file is indeed no longer `.json`. I made sure that <kbd>Notepad++</kbd> is the default program to handle `.json` and the problem persists.

Comment: Do you have "File Name Extensions" Checked in the View tab?

Comment: No dice, checked the box resaved with a new file name.

Comment: can you show us an image of the file you saved and post it here?

Comment: When you save the file, you can use quotes to force a file extension save. Do not even change the filetype dropdown when saving, just type  "myFile.json" in quotes and see if it works

Comment: The force worked as described by Nazard. I should have thought of that, thanks to both of you.